# Catch all dynamic route in Next.js results in unwanted link in sitemap using next-sitemap package

Tags: next.js, url-routing, sitemap

In my `Next.js` application I am using the catch all functionality of dynamic routing. When I use the package [next-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sitemap) for creating a sitemap I see in the file `sitemap-0.xml` there is a link like:

`https://example.com/posts/1/2/3/4/5`.

I believe this corresponds with the getStaticPaths function in the file [...posts.js] like below:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const dbRows = await getPostIds();
    const postIds = dbRows.map(post => post['post_id'])
    return {
        paths: [{params: {postId: postIds}}],
        fallback: 'blocking',
    }
}
```

Luckily the next-sitemap package offers to exclude pages. So this might be a solution for me. Though somehow I have the feeling the solution is in `Next.js` itself or the next-sitemap package itself besides using the exclude config.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by providing all path parameters instead of just an array of post ids.

Solution:

```
paths: 

    [{params: {postId: ['Python', '1']}},
            {params: {postId: ['Java', '2']}}]
```